# PHP file upload throwing errors

Tags: php, file-upload

I have writen this php handler for uploading files to my server. It worked when i made some tests and now suddently it is throwing errors.

This is the errors:

> **Warning**: implode(): Argument must be an array in /path/to/file/upload.php on line 7
>
> **Warning**: implode(): Argument must be an array in /path/to/file/upload.php on line 12

This is my handler:

```
<?php

error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . implode( $_FILES[ "upload" ][ "name" ] );
$uploadOk = 1;
$FileType = ( pathinfo( $target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );

// Check file size
if ( implode( $_FILES[ "upload" ][ "size" ] ) > 500000000000 ) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if ( $FileType != "zip" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only ZIP files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ( $uploadOk == 0 ) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if ( move_uploaded_file( implode( $_FILES[ "upload" ][ "tmp_name" ] ),  $target_file ) ) {
        echo "The file " . implode( $_FILES[ "upload" ][ "name" ] ) . " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

And this is my form:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="upload" type="file"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

I have trouble understanding how it can just stop working when i do not touch it. Any ideas why it is not working?

Comment: `$_FILES[ "upload" ][ "name" ]` is a __string__, why do you implode it?

Comment: Becaus when i do not implode it it tells me that it is not a string

Comment: `print_r($_FILES)` to see what you have.

Comment: This is the output of the print: `Array ( [upload] => Array ( [name] => Twitter_bird_logo_2012.zip [type] => application/x-zip-compressed [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpvbCP3C [error] => 0 [size] => 4709 ) )`

Comment: So, `name` key is a __string__, no `implode` is required.

Comment: If it's target file and directory you want there you should probably use: `$target_file = $target_dir . $_FILES[ "upload" ][ "name" ] ;`

Comment: And the other implode should also be removed. `if ( implode( $_FILES[ "upload" ][ "size" ] ) > 500000000000 ) {` => `if ( $_FILES[ "upload" ][ "size" ]  > 500000000000 ) {`

Comment: Here is the documentation of implode http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: Oh my God! You got more implodes! Remove em all!

Comment: I have removed the implodes and now i get this error: **Warning**: move_uploaded_file(): Argument must be a string in /path/to/file/upload.php on line 26

Comment: Yes it's supposed to be string http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php . What did you do? If you only removed implode() the value should be string

Comment: This is the line `move_uploaded_file( $_FILES[ "upload" ][ "tmp_name" ], $target_file )`

Comment: I know.. See below on my answer. I think I found all errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.
Removed all the implodes that is not supposed to be there.

```
<?php

error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . $_FILES[ "upload" ][ "name" ] ;
$uploadOk = 1;
$FileType = ( pathinfo( $target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );

// Check file size
if ( $_FILES[ "upload" ][ "size" ]  > 500000000000 ) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if ( $FileType != "zip" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only ZIP files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ( $uploadOk == 0 ) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if ( move_uploaded_file($_FILES[ "upload" ][ "tmp_name" ] , $target_file ) ) {  
        echo "The file " . $_FILES[ "upload" ][ "name" ]  . " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: @McMuffin Thank you. Implode is used to piece together an array with a "glue". In your case you try to implode a string which won't work. Had you done `echo implode(" THE GLUE ", $_FILES);` you will see what implode does. Just don't use that line in your code. it's just for demostration purpose

Answer (score 0):

$_FILE['upload']['name'] is a string You cannot implode it

if you want its name you don't have to implode it just use

```
  fileName = $_FILE['upload']['name'];
  $targDir = "uploads/";
  $tagFile = $tagDir.$fileName
```

will do it